# Is there a possibility in Mediawiki to have a diff of different pages on interwiki linked wikis?

Tags: diff, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm looking for a possibility to diff pages from different wikis that are linked by interwiki links. The wikis are like forks and I'd like to be able to diff the two versions of the content in the different wikis. Is there an extension or a separate utility that can handle this? By thinking closer I suppose the first step of this question would be if there is a possibility of having a diff of different pages in one wiki.

Comment: The first part of the question - comparing pages - was easy to solve as there is a special page "Special:ComparePages". But as far as I can see it only compares pages in the same wiki.

Comment: Similar question has been asked on Mediawiki wiki: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:W8h5ts4iaetnpk4c

Answer (score 0):

I think your least bad option is to fetch the remote content and craft a link to the edit form with that content and have it generate a diff, using [query parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Edit_and_submit). DifferenceEngine, where most of the diff rendering code lives, takes revision IDs and does not let you interfere much with loading the page contents (and it's generally not developer-friendly code).

If you just want to generate a diff between two pieces of content, e.g. on a special page you have created for this purpose, `SlotDiffRenderer::getDiff()` is easy to use for that, but if you want to recreate the full diff layout (multiple slots, a header etc) you'll have to copy significant parts of the DifferenceEngine codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll look into it. I just had the idea to copy the remote page content to a temporary local page and diff that.

Comment: Well, that certainly works if you don't mind the extra pages.